# Gettting data from georeferenced PNG QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, georeferencing, heat-map, comparison

I'm working on a predictive system and was able to locate a PNG from another researcher showing a heat map of Oklahoma.  I was able to georeference the PNG and bring it into QGIS 3.22.  What I need to do is count the dots (red, green, yellow) which are on another layer that occur in a specific color of the heat map.  I have no access to the data which created the heatmap, just the PNG that I brought in.

I've tried this manually, getting the band values for the heatmap, but that is kind of confusing.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  In a GIS those colors would just be rendered colors representing the values of some underlying spatial data.  With a PNG that you found, download, and georeferenced all you are going to get are RGB values of the PNG.  If you had the data you would be able to use any number of tools to populate the points with the values of the raster data.  Contact the researcher and ask nicely for their data.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I doubt if I will be able to get the data, as my research contradicts theirs.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe these data are subject to a FOIA request?  https://www.foia.gov/

Comment: Thanks, but I doubt it.  This if from a science journal that isn't connected to the government.  I was able to bring the screen into gimp, switch it to 256 colors then manually estimate the values, that worked for what I needed to do.